# How will prevent triggering navLink/link in react router when click right icon button with nested list item? Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a sample code here: ListItem with nested list I want to prevent the link and trigger the nested list. Or I want when I click the rightIconButton only triggers the nested list not the link.

```
<ListItem 
   value={3}
   primaryText="My Collection"
   leftIcon={<Avatar src="http://i.imgur.com/fmvLZGS.png" />}
   initiallyOpen={false}
   containerElement={<NavLink to="/CollectionPage" />}
   nestedItems={[
     <ListItem
        value={4}
        key={1}
        primaryText="Wines"/>,
     <ListItem
        value={5}
        key={2}
        primaryText="Arts"/>,
     <ListItem
        value={6}
        key={3}
        primaryText="Vehicles"/>
  ]} />
```

Thank you!

Comment: remove pointer events https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/